# What is the difference between "." and "/" in java classname?

Tags: java, class

I'm new to java. When I try to learn [Maven in 5 minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), I found that this command

```
java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App
```

worked the same way as

```
java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com/mycompany/app/App
```

It drives me crazy because the last argument in the second command is actually a path. What is the difference between "." and "/" in java classname?

I have looked up some articles but still don't get it.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but the slashes are just part of a path name.  On the hard drive, your class is actually located at src/com/mycompany/app/App.java.  Because the path and the class name are so closely related, the `java` command will just assume you mean . when you type / and do the translation for you.

Comment: `com.mycompany.app.App` is *full package name of class* from which you want to run its `main` method. But `com.mycompany.app.` means that `App` class should be inside `com/mycompany/app/` directories that notation was also *allowed* (I don't remember since which Java version). So both represent same information. In other words `com.mycompany.app.App` should work in all Java versions but `com/mycompany/app/App` in *most* Java versions.

Comment: In other words, `.` is the correct name of the class, and `/` is only used for path names on the hard drive.  But `java` (the command) is aware that they are both used, and so will accept either.

Comment: I'm going to leave my comment up, but it appears the correct answer is completely the opposite.  The slashes are added by the tool (in this case the `java` command).  If there's no dots in the original class name, the tool just doesn't notice and passes the original string to the OS as a filename, which does work (under Windows, the OS, not Java, will notice that you've used a Unix path with forward slashes and switch them to Windows style back slashes, so forward slashes do actually work everywhere).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an implementation detail leaking out.  Largely for irrelevant historical reasons, class names in the language are dot-separated but class names in the classfile format are slash-separated.  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.2.)  For the most part, internal names are not visible to users, but they do leak in some circumstances.  Many tools that deal with classfiles will convert from the external (dotted) to internal (slashed) name using something like `replace('.', '/')`, which has the effect that internal names are also accepted by the tool.  That's what's going on here.